# Why are disjunctive pronouns called disjunctive?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

The [Oxford Dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/definition/disjunctive) says that in grammar, the adjective "disjunctive" can only be applied to conjunctions, and disjunctive conjunctions (like or) express two mutually exclusive possibilites. However, [Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disjunctive) has a different definition:

> (grammar, of a personal pronoun) Not used in immediate conjunction with the verb of which the pronoun is the subject.

Disjunctive pronouns in French are personal pronouns, not conjunctions, so Wikitionary's definition should apply here. Why is

> Lui n’est pas au courant de cela.

gramatically correct then?

How does the "discrete" meaning of disjunctive apply to the disjunctive pronouns in French?

Answer (score 2):

***Lui*** looks indeed like the subject of the sentence:

> ***Lui*** n’est pas au courant de cela.

but the sentence can be understood as a shortened version of:

> ***Lui***, **il** n’est pas au courant de cela. (He himself is unaware of that)

where *lui* is effectively disjunctive, in apposition. *Lui* is emphatic and *il*, being redundant, is dropped.

Comment: Hmm... How does this explanation apply to object form: « Ce n'est pas difficile pour lui » ?

Comment: @LukeSawczak That's a different case but in that sentence, the pronoun *lui* is still disjunctive, isn't it?

Comment: It is still disjunctive, and hence (I think) a difficulty for your explanation. When it's the subject, you argue that it's disjoined from an implicit *il*. What is it disjoined from when it's the object?

Comment: @LukeSawczak I was more trying to explain why *Lui n'est pas...* is acceptable in French than anything else. These pronouns are more often called *pronoms toniques* than *pronoms disjoints* in French, but here is a page where they are: http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/301.html

Comment: @LukeSawczak By the way, I meant it is disjointed from the verb by an implicit *il*. In *Ce n'est pas difficile pour lui*, it is disjointed at least by the preposition *pour*.

Comment: That sounds more compelling :)